# How do I set up passwordless authentication with non-root users?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, networking

Using two CentOS 7 servers, I set up passwordless authentication with root users.  It works fine. I tried to use the same method (with .pub and authorized_key files) with other local users.  But these methods didn't work.  SSH connections between the servers with these users still prompted for a password.

I started with this:  `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

One of my servers is Jenkins. I want to do builds (file transfers at the least) with other CentOS 7 servers.  I think I need passwordless authentication for the jenkins user.  I tried appending the contents of the `.pub` files in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  I tried appending the contents of the `.pub` files in `/home/jdoe/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  Instead of authorized_keys I also tried `authorized_keys2`.  I expect passwordless authentication to work the same way with root as other users (as long as I don't enter a password when I generate the SSH key).  But this isn't what I am experiencing.  The root users can authenticate with no password over SSH.  Non-root users aren't doing that. What should I do?

Comment: you should use "-v" for ssh session and observe debug information. My guess : check if file permissions for jdoe user' ssh keys. This user has to be the owner of whole .ssh dir, file permissions has to be set to 600.

Comment: The SSH server logs provide the most useful information for debugging SSH connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're more than likely running into a snag on the permissions. I usually leave `authorized_keys` to be `400` (though `640` will suffice). `~/.ssh` should be `700`. `id_rsa` I keep `400` as well. The less permissions the files have, the more ssh will be fine with them.

If you use the `-v` switch on ssh, it will tell you this issue. `/var/log/secure` will also tell you what's going on.

As a rule of thumb, `ssh-copy-id` will take care of all of this for you. If you run it and then the keys start working, look at the permissions of the files after the fact.